# How to bypass ActionAfterProcess for 0 sized file in wso2 esb

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am using below configuration to move files from one folder to another.But I dont want to move or delete the files of 0 size in "in" folder.pls help me.

```
<parameter name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileURI">vfs:file://E:\\orders</parameter>
<parameter name="Operation">urn:saveOrder</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.PollInterval">5</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">MOVE</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterProcess">file:///E:\out</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">file:///E:\in</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterFailure">file:///E:\fails</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">.*\.xml</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">application/xml</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterFailure">MOVE</parameter>
```

Comment: can you explain your requirement a bit further? It is hard to understand what are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use ActionAfterProcess

Inside your inSequence, use send mediator to write the file to your destination :

```
<send>
    <endpoint>
        <address uri="file:///E:\out"/>
    </endpoint>
</send>
```

Use filter mediator to decide if this send must be executed or not, depending on the value of FILE_LENGTH : `get-property('transport','FILE_LENGTH')`